# Open Layers 3 new layer types

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers

We want to use Open Layers 3 to render a set of data on top of a world map.
We already have our own renderer for the custom data. This renderer uses the HTML5 Canvas element for the drawing.

The coordinates in our own renderer are already in lat/long so they should be easy to project on a world map. However we want to reuse as much of our original code as possible.

Is it possible to create a new layer type in Open Layers? I'm thinking about a single canvas on which we can just render using our old code and do a custom transform based on the view given by Open Layers.

So I think what my question basically boils down to is can I create new layer types in OpenLayers and how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Have a look at the [ol.source.ImageCanvas](http://ol3js.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.source.ImageCanvas.html)

Comment: Hello Gaby. Thanks for replying. I took a look at the documentation but couldn't find how to use this layer. Do you know where I can find some examples or guides?